# Lightbox won't fire onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My Fancybox form won't fire when I click on it. I'm sure I copied the source code from Fancybox correctly. I just need help figuring out why it won't fire. I update the jquery but that still doesn't seem to help. I got the source code from [here](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples); just scroll down a bit until you see inline and ajax along with a list of other inline lightboxes. I'm trying to get the "Inline" lightbox for my website but it won't fire.

Fancybox: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples (I'm trying to get "Inline - auto detect width / height" near the bottom of the webpage)

Here's what I tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/js/fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if ($(window).width() < 960) {
$('footer').css('padding', '20px');
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<ul>
<li><a id="various1" href="#inline1" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet">Inline - auto detect width / height</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a start, you will need to add the `jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js` after the `jquery.js`

Comment: I don't quite understand. I already have "jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js" in the code.

Comment: For a start, you will need to add the jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js **after** the jquery.js

Comment: You said that already. I didn't understand it the first time.

Comment: I moved the code around if that's what you meant. I'm a bit confused because I'm literally looking for "jquery.js" and I don't see it.

Comment: Now you question has been edited so jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js is now after the jquery.js you know need to use fancybox on an element e.g. $(".myfancybox").fancybox();

Comment: Everything should already be ready for use. I copied it right from the website. I don't get this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38584/discussion-between-user2680614-and-user2310289)

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with jquery. I just need examples or a bit more help. Can you help?

Comment: for future reference, anytime you see a js file like jquery.min.js, the .min means minified ie removing comments,newlines, obfuscation etc to make the file as small in file size. so when you see jquery.js, it is an unminfied version of jquery.min.js. they terms are interchangable